# branching model for Flash Builder project?

Tags: flash, version-control, air, flash-builder

Assume the following situation:

You work on a AIR Application with Flash Builder. Since the last release (let's say 1.2), you're working on several new features - the next release (1.3) will be ready in a few weeks. However, now you get some crucial bugs to fix and must release a version 1.2.1 on short term.

The problem is now, how you do that?
You cannot use the current state of your project, as there are many unfinished/untested new functions in.

Alternatively, you can checkout your SVN revision from the last published version into a new folder and work on the bugfix there. But then, in order to have the bugfix also in the new version you're working on you will have to copy over all your code changes and make sure not to forget anything.

Can someone tell me how to handle such cases properly with an AIR project?

Comment: Nothing special about AIR projects. This branching model (dev, main, release, hotfix) applies to all software. Just make sure you can check-out the release version (the one deployed and has bugs) and do bug fixes on it. The normal procedure is to retro-fit the fixes into the other branches if necessary. Even the [TFS VS2k10 branching guide](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/releases/view/38849) applies.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather unrelated to Flash/AIR projects; the same applies to just any project. What you should do is using the branching functionality of your version control system. In your case, create a branch in SVN that branches off the release revision 1.2. Then make your bug fixes on that branch. For your normal work for the next release, continue using the trunk.